# What is the Real Quickbooks Online API?

Tags: php, api, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I've been researching this for a while, and I really can't find the right solution.  I found this PHP API that is supposed to help solve all these issues, but it doesn't work - or it's not clear how to set it up correctly.

This is the PHP api I've tried to use
<strike>https://code.intuit.com/sf/frs/do/viewRelease/projects.php_devkit/frs.php_devkit.latest_sources</strike>

- Updated link: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- Updated quick-start guide: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

I was able to get OAUTH to connect on the ipp developer site, so that's nice. But I can't get any data.

I'm just trying to automate some processes for my company with our quickbooks - online store integration.

Basically I just don't understand what to do to get say a list of POs from quickbooks online.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code works just fine - you're just doing something wrong. (I know - I'm the developer of that code, and I work with it *every* *single* *day* doing exactly the sort of thing you're looking to do).

With that said, since you didn't post *any* code or *any* error messages, no one is going to be able to help you.

**Post some code or error messages.**

Other specifics:

> But I can't get any data.

Why not? What specific error are you getting? What does your code look like? What type of data are you trying to get?

> I'm just trying to automate some processes for my company with our quickbooks - online store integration.

If all you're building is a one-off/custom integration for *your* company, then you've started down the wrong path. Intuit Anywhere (the OAuth stuff) is for SaaS applications only (see the FAQs here: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0080_FAQ, specifically this one: "I want to integrate my custom (non-SaaS, single-tenant) solution with Intuit Anywhere. Can I do this?").

Instead, you should be using qbXML. Download the STABLE release:
 [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/)

And look at docs/example_online_edition.php

The rest of Intuit's documentation *for qbXML* (not Intuit Anywhere) is here: 
http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

> Basically I just don't understand what to do to get say a list of POs from quickbooks online.

Unfortunately, you'll find that fetching Purchase Orders is not supported by EITHER of the two APIs available for QuickBooks Online.

All of the QuickBooks Online APIs that Intuit provides have always been incomplete. Neither supports Purchase Orders. If you really need Purchase Order support, switch to QuickBooks for Windows instead.

**If you need more help/have trouble, MAKE SURE you post your code and any error messages so that we can help you further!!!**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  You're right, facepalm on my part for not posting any errors. But that's in part because the confusion on what I'm supposed to be trying.

I couldn't for example figure what a "$dbid" was supposed to be - All i got from the IPP was the app key, and oauth stuff.

But in terms of errors, I get

    Notice: Undefined variable: Context in    /var/www/qb/docs/example_ipp_basics.php on line 51

Which is with no modifications other than just changing out my variables
    

as seen here
https://market.mp3car.com/qb/docs/example_ipp_basics.php

Comment: Also thanks for the data on where to go to make a 1 off application, not a SaaS app. That was probably the most confusing, I knew it felt wrong to go down that path, but there was so much misinformation in all the docs that I was reading.

I'm used to APIs where I can just download the sample code and get to work.  QB seems more like Google. Need to have these 5 libraries, read these 4 PDFs then you can try connecting to our system.

Comment: @SeanClark Yeah it's sort of a PITA, Intuit certainly doesn't make it easy. The qbXML interface is much easier to get started with. Register in DESKTOP mode as a PRODUCTION (not PTC) app and it's pretty easy to get started: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition Unfortunately the QuickBooks Online APIs kind of suck...

Comment: @SeanClark On and thanks for the note about that example file - it's broken. We will fix and/or remove from SVN. The real place to start with OAuth is docs/example_ipp_oauth.php and docs/example_ipp_ids_5.php (and we're working to make that more evident/clear). Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I just sent you an email with more details, and Ill come back here and post the answer, or you can - when I figure out the final solution.

Comment: So I guess this is considered getting farther. But I still can't make the calls.  here is the debugged output to look at

https://market.mp3car.com/qb2/docs/example_online_edition.php

Comment: Did you register in DESKTOP mode, or HOSTED mode? If you registered in DESKTOP mode, make sure you're not specifying a non-existant certificate in your code. If you registered in HOSTED mode... then you need to go back and register in DESKTOP mode like I indicated previously. :-)   (unless you really want to spend the next week of your life tearing your hair out trying to get HOSTED mode to work...)

Comment: I did use Desktop mode. The comment said to "safely ignore the certificate" which I know now means to delete what's there.

So some new fun errors
https://market.mp3car.com/qb2/docs/example_online_edition.php

Last error message: No agency privilege
Exception from other package:
 com.intuit.platform.services.qbn.domain.auth.AuthMgrException

Again, thanks a billion for your help.

Comment: Post what you used for your appreg settings.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is the ticket, since I didn't change it or find what I'm supposed to change it to.

'connection_ticket' => 'TGT-47-1sRm2nXMVfm$n8hb2MZfVQ', 
'application_login' => 'mp3car.market.mp3car.com', 
'application_id' => '310397596',

http://cl.ly/image/1E33352L1L3Y

Comment: Follow the directions I already posted for registering in DESKTOP mode: wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition When you follow the URL to connect to QuickBooks, it'll make you log in and give you your connection ticket.

Comment: Damn - I'm sorry you're right you did post where to get that.  I was looking all over the php file for that. Haha this information is all over the place.  At any rate - now that part is working, i'm getting this guy.

Last error number: 2020
Last error message: Session Authentication required

Comment: Ok so I redid the process and told it turn OFF login security. I think that whole part works now. I just have to study the API to figure out what I can do with it.

Comment: The only issue left I guess is that in your demo script, it gets to this line

$API->addCustomer($Customer, '_add_customer_callback', 15);

But never returns, and doesn't call the callback. It also doesn't actually add the customer to my QB.  Any ideas?

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Post the code up on our forums and we can take more of a look: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/

Comment: @KeithPalmer-consolibyte I found this link to be blank https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164&enterthread=y
was looking for the code for QBO with PHP

Comment: Updated code is here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php   Intuit broke all the old links on us.

Comment: Follow this quick-start guide: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

Answer (score 1):

Try this Dev kit :

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

It was good sdk that was worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it shouldn't be too difficult with `curl`(1) or something. https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#PurchaseOrder

Answer (score 0):

Quickbooks seems to abandon their links faster than they create them.  I'm trying to build a SAAS application with QuickBooks API interfacing can't find the SAAS stuff mentioned above and the link is dead.

Does anyone know if the two different APIs mentioned above have now been merged?

Comment: use developer.intuit.com they have a fantastic API now. You don't need any SDK they are very simple REST calls.

Comment: Hey Sean, dam that was quick.  Many thanks for the response.  I'm on developer.intuit.com now and it looks so easy I was suspicious I was missing something!  So the new API is suitable for SAAS implementations (not just custom inhouse development).  We are building a webapp and we want customers to be able to authorize our app to link to their QuickBooks online account

Comment: Yea you just need to implement the oAuth workflow so your app can get authorized. The rest is the same as if it was an internal app.