# Quick book integration in php , getting connection issues

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am integrating `quickbook` online API using PHP but we are facing many problems in it.
First, I am not able to connect with `quickbook` using my demo API. 
I have found token and access key but still i am not able to connect.

Second, there is no any sample code for php and there is no any online support team.
Can any help me to connect with quick book API?

I have created developer account from below [link](https://developer.intuit.com/)

Comment: i have found this secret key 
<add key="AccessToken" value="lvprdxRfMJvLcj2SiGTGmDnGnIzgwtzvrx6aXOkusaY5VaHD" />
<add key="AccessTokenSecret" value="29srGl2arkoemavtdCzKRfto491646jeEqsgpcjP" />
 <add key="ConsumerKey" value="qyprd7JkXyZZBINAlw1gnWmWyWYoxS" />
  <add key="ConsumerSecret" value="DCUNn0tR3nShmf9vSBijybVca2pwGVlUj9NJ8v3Q" />
  <add key="RealmID" value="1440840010" />

Comment: Post your code. Post any errors you're seeing. Post the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your code, or any error messages, or really much of any details at all, no one is really going to be able to help you. *Post your code and the error messages if you want a good answer*.

In the meantime, I'm not sure which PHP code you're using, but if you're using this one:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Then there's tons of examples here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3

And a quick-start guide you should have followed here:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

Comment: I have follewed this step , its working fine..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393709/quickbooks-api-php-integration
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988649/what-is-the-real-quickbooks-online-api

From GIT
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/02/25/quickbooks-oauth-php-example

https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/772099-quickbooks-online-integration-php-using-qbxml-not-functional